# Why isn't the $display function printing any value?

Tags: verilog

The code for TPG module

```
module TPG(input wire clk, input wire reset, input wire bistMode, input wire enable, output reg[127:0] valueO);

reg[31:0] myPatterns[0:3],Temporary;
integer i;

always@(posedge clk)begin

    if((bistMode==1) && (enable==1))begin

        if(reset)begin
            Temporary = 32'b11111111111111111111111111111111;
        end
            else
        begin

            for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)begin
                Temporary = {(Temporary[31] ^ Temporary[25] ^ Temporary[22] ^ Temporary[21] ^ Temporary[15] ^ Temporary[11] ^ Temporary[10] ^ Temporary[9] ^ Temporary[7] ^ Temporary[6] ^ Temporary[4] ^ Temporary[3] ^ Temporary[1] ^ Temporary[0]), Temporary[31:1]};
                myPatterns[i] = Temporary;
            end
            valueO = {myPatterns[3],myPatterns[2],myPatterns[1],myPatterns[0]};

        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

The code for testbench is given below.

```
`timescale 10ns/1ns
module mux_tb();

reg clk,resetting,bistForDeterministic,enable,bistMode;
wire [127:0] valueI;

 TPG T (clk,resetting,bistMode,enable,valueI);

initial begin
    clk = 0;
    resetting = 1;
    #5 resetting = 0;
    bistForDeterministic = 1;
    bistMode = 1;
    enable = 1;
end

always@(negedge clk)begin

    if((bistMode==1) && (bistForDeterministic==1))begin

        @(valueI)begin
            $display("%h",valueI);
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$display` does not print any value because the testbench is not driving your inputs properly.

Your clock signal is always 0, which means you never saw any `negedge`.  Also, you were not assigning other signals during reset (`enable` and `bistMode`).

These changes to the testbench allow the `$display` to print values:

```
initial begin
    clk = 0;
    resetting = 1;
    bistForDeterministic = 1;
    bistMode = 1;
    enable = 1;
    #5 resetting = 0;
    #100 $finish;
end

always #1 clk = ~clk;
```

You should adjust the clock period and other signal timing for your purposes.

---

I was able to debug this problem by dumping waveforms during simulation and viewing them in a waveform viewer.  This is usually more efficient than just relying on printing information in a log file.